# Pythonanywhere Loading data from local files

Tags: database, python-2.7, pythonanywhere

I'm new to pythonanywhere. I wonder how to load data from local csv files (there are many of them, over 1,000) into a mysql table. Let's say the path for the folder of the csv files is d:/data. How can I write let pythonanywhere visit the local files? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try [this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ImportingYourLocalDatabaseToPythonAnywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get PythonAnywhere to read the files directly off your machine. At the very least, you need to upload the file to PythonAnywhere first. You can do that from the Files tab. Then the link that Rptk99 provided will show you how to import the file into MySQL.